# Access denied connecting to TFS Server

Tags: tfs, terminal, azure-devops

I am connecting to TFS server using terminal on my MacBook according to the website: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019. Yes i have created the workspace successfully but when I try to map it to local folder, it always shows error about access denied even though my credentials is absolutely correct, I am using personal access token as username and leave empty for the password.

The error is:
Access denied connecting to TFS server https://dev.azure.com/myworkbaseasolutemobile/VersionControl/v4.0/repository.asmx (authenticating as f). After that, it prompt me to enter the username and password, once I type in, terminal do nothing but give me new line to enter the new command. When I entered the tf workfold command again, the error comes out again.

I don't even know where is the 'f' comes from. I don't know where is the problem. Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Username should be blank. PAT is the password.

Answer (score 0):

Personal access tokens (PATs) **are alternate passwords** that you can use to authenticate into Azure DevOps.

Azure DevOps uses enterprise-grade authentication to help protect and secure your data. Clients like Visual Studio and Eclipse (with the Team Explorer Everywhere plug-in) also support Microsoft account and Azure AD authentication. Since PATs are an alternate form of user authentication, using a PAT gives you the same access level. If you create a PAT with a narrower scope, your access is limited to that scope.

Please leave the username empty and use PAT as password to access your TFS server.

Besides, , since you are using PAT with on-premise TFS server, check if you already turned off Basic Authentication.

> We recommend you keep IIS Basic Authentication turned off at all times
>   when using Azure DevOps Server. Only if necessary should you enable
>   IIS Basic Authentication. When IIS Basic Authentication is enabled on
>   your windows machine, it prevents you from using personal access
>   tokens (PATs) as an authentication mechanism.

More details please take a look at this [official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth?view=azure-devops).

Comment: @JCYOUNG  Thanks for getting back to me. Are you behind a network proxy? Are you able to directly access TFS web portal instead of Visual Studio Mac ? This will help to narrow down the issue related to Visual Studio Mac side or your network environment.

Comment: Yes, I am able to access TFS web portal directly. No worry, I have fix the issue by installing Eclipse and use it for check in and check out the code and sync with Visual Studio.

Comment: how can I move my comment to solution?

Comment: @JCYOUNG Just add a new solution with your comments and expand a little with some details. Finally mark the reply.